# OS X Filevault Login issue

Tags: macos, filevault, login

I just reformatted and did a clean OS X 10.10 install on my MacBook Pro.

When setting it up the first time I enabled FileVault. I then noticed I had configured my account wrong, so I created a temporary admin account (simply called `Admin`) and removed my initial account, and created a new account with admin access. I then logged in to the new account and removed the temporary `Admin` account.

Now, when I start the computer, [this happens](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cdr0h6oxk612pet/2014-11-05%2012.50.27.mp4?dl=0) (Dropbox video link).

The `Admin` account is nowhere to be seen. Not in `Preferences -> Accounts`, or using any kind of `dscacheutil` or `dscl` commands.

When checking who has access to decrypting the disk there's only one account, and it's the new account I created (correct one).

I can only log in to the temporary account I created, then after a long black screen I can log in to my correct account. Is this working as intended?

Answer (score 1):

How did you check which account can decrypt the disk?

I suspect (WAG) what happened is that you set up your new account so that it duplicates the UID of the previous admin account, so it shows up in one place as being authorized, but is not actually authorized. You removed account IS authorized for file vault, even thought eh account no longer exists on the unix-y side of things.

I'd try all this again, making sure to add the new accounts with new UIDs and that you add them to the FileVault list.

Comment: I deactivated FileVault. Haven't tried reactivating it yet, but I'm pretty sure it'll work as expected.